# PHP extension returns different system errors fom CLI and apache2 module

Tags: php, linux

This is a code fragment of a function inside a PHP extension. The long parameter passed "fd" is irrelevant and not used.

```
PHP_FUNCTION(crtest) { int fd ; FILE *fp ;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &fd) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

    fp = fopen("/usr/pkg/php-5.6.30/ext/cisam/tests/tfile", "w") ;
    php_printf("fopen   : %d\n", errno) ;
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "/usr/pkg/php-5.6.30/ext/cisam/tests/tfile") ;
    php_printf("fprintf : %d\n", errno) ;
    fclose(fp) ;
    php_printf("fclose  : %d\n", errno) ;

    RETURN_LONG(errno) ;

}
```

The strange thing here is:

- When running from cli the function ALWAYS returns error 25 (ENOTTY)
- When running from apache2 module on all operations error 2 (ENOFILE) is returned. (Permissions for the web server are fixed).

BUT in BOTH CASES the operation is COMPLETED NORMALLY besides the error. Any help or hint?

PHP is 5.6.30